# Javascript recognition of type

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain me how this syntax works?

```
export function isGroup(recipient: Recipient): recipient is Group {
    return "Name" in recipient;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's JavaScript and not TypeScript or something else?

Comment: Definitely not JavaScript.

Comment: Have you checked the Typescript docs/spec at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not JavaScript at all - it's TypeScript**. ES6 does not have type annotations.

Breaking down this statement:

`exports` - [this is an ES6 feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

> The export statement is used to export functions, objects or
>   primitives from a given file (or module)

`recipient : Recipient` - a type annotation indicating that recipient is of type Recipient (TypeScript)

`recipient is Group` - this is a [user defined type guard](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-defined-type-guard-functions) (TypeScript 1.6)

`"name" in recipient` - this is just [vanilla JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), originally defined in ES3:

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!